# The variable has not been assigned

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[This code is basically using the code from https://gist.github.com/runewake2/b4b7bf73485222f7c5a0fe0c91dd1322**strong text**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUmhv.png)

I have already assigned the variable but still got this error. Can anybody tell me how? I watched this guy tutorial and he did it with this code so there shouldn't be a problem I guess.

[image]

Comment: Please provide [mcve] and not a link to image of your code...

Comment: 1. Please post your code/errors as formatted text instead of a screenshot. 2. Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: Which line of code is it complaining about?

Comment: This question is liable to **downvotes** because you didn't provide a MCVE, and you didn't identify specifically the potential causes of the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't initialize the property `private Material material;` When you create object like that you create a reference that points to `null`. In your code you are trying to modify this object but since it's not initialized it's `null`. The solution is to initialize it in the constructor like so:

```
public FlowLines() 
{
     this.material = new Material();
}
```

Comment: or `material = this.gameObject.getComponent<MeshRenderer>().material;`

Comment: Yes @Draco18s Your DI is much better :)